# how to stop a fixed input at the top of a page from making the ipad browser scroll up on focus

Tags: javascript, ios, input, scroll

I have a responsive site where the top navigation is fixed so as you scroll down the age the header stay at the top edge of the browser. In the header is a search input. On iphones and ipads, when the user taps in to the field the page scroll to the top.

I want to stop this because say the user decides not to search and taps out of the search field, they should bee where they left off versus at the top of the page.

I have found articles about using overflows on scrollable divs, but this is not the case this is just a plain page. I have anchor book marks that allows the user to go to sections of the page, and lots of home page content. I want the user to be able to drag their way down the page, or click on an anchor. Then have the ability to click the search and not have the page zip to the top.

How would I go about this with javascript I have tried preventDefault on focus of the field with no luck.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Jeff